# How to find the dependencies of the webpack runtime?

Tags: webpack

Creating a web app project with create-react-app will also include react-scripts, which in turn uses Webpack. The generated bundles (chunks) use webpack at runtime. For this scenario I need to list all 4th party dependencies used by webpack **at runtime**.

Unfortunately, Webpack is not directly part of my dependencies list in the `package.json` file. The only reference I can find is when I dump the dependency tree using `npm ls`. However, that includes many dev dependencies, for which I don't need approvals (acorn, webassembly etc.).

Checking https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack, also gives me a list of dependencies. But that list differs signficantly from the tree as generated above and it also includes dev dependencies, like @types/eslint-scope or @types/estree.

The Webpack webpage has a lot of information, but I could not find what I'm looking for, particularly also because "Webpack (runtime) dependencies" as a term is discussed at great length for app dependencies, leading so to a completely wrong path.

I then downloaded the [Webpack zip](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/archive/v4.44.2.zip) from Github and inspected that. It contains a folder with many dependencies, but I'm very unsure if that's actually the deps list I need, as the content doesn't appear to be node modules.

What else can I do to get such a list?

Comment: Those `@types` modules *are* [non-dev dependencies](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/16774961d4f9371251c96adf98618675eb032f30/package.json#L7-L31) (not sure whether they should be, though), distinct from the [dev dependencies](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/16774961d4f9371251c96adf98618675eb032f30/package.json#L38-L106). The zip file you've downloaded is just the source code, which explicitly [excludes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/16774961d4f9371251c96adf98618675eb032f30/.gitignore#L1) `node_modules/` as is conventional.

Comment: The downloaded zip contains a package.json which includes acorn as a runtime dependency. I doubt webpack needs a parser at runtime, so I wonder how exact this list is.

Comment: It's reliant on whether anyone set `-D`/`--save-dev` when installing a dependency and/or reviewed the inclusion before merging, there's no technical requirement to put all dev dependencies in `devDependencies`. I'm not really certain what your context is here, what you mean by "runtime" as far as Webpack goes or what having this list of dependencies helps you with.

Comment: I assume the term "runtime" is known to you (the library/libraries used when an app runs, in opposition to the term "design time" or "development", where an app is, well, being developed. React uses Webpack to generate the output files of a web app (aka. production build) at development (or rather build) time. This build requires certain libraries to execute, for example the Webpack runtime, but also a few others). Because this "runtime" is shipped to customers, it is very important to know, what code is actually shipped. Many companies need to approve that, for legal reasons.

Comment: In that case I guess you're really asking what's in the bundles - look at the source maps (`.js.map` files) whose `sources` property tells you where the code in them came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tool called [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer), which parses the generated bundles and provides information (and an interactive graphic) for all the included code. The graphic shows which module ended up in which bundle at which size (bundle size + gzipped):

[image]

I used this tool too verify that no 3rd party runtime code injected by Webpack exists in the bundles, which answers my question pretty well. Third party plugins may add something, but that's a different story.

Comment: *"no runtime code from Webpack exists in the bundles"* - I don't think that's true, the build output for a vanilla CRA ([here's](https://github.com/textbook/rps-e2e) one I made earlier) includes a `runtime-main.<hash>.js` that includes Webpack's bootstrap code.

Comment: You are right. Bad wording from my side. I'll change the text.